# Goto was unexpected time

Tags: batch-file

When I run the script Console prints `goto was unexpected time`, (I have bad English)

```
@echo on
set versiyon=0.1
if %komut1%=="metin" goto metinapi
if %komut1%=="internet" goto internetapi
if %komut1%=="dosya" goto dosyaapi
if %komut1%=="sistem" goto sistem
if %komut1%=="versiyon"(
    echo %versiyon%
    pause
) 
color c 
echo Hata:Aranan sey bulunamadi!Aradiginiz seyi dogru yazdiginizdan emin 
olun!ya da frameworku guncelleyin. suanki verisyon:%versiyon% KOD:1
pause
:metinapi
if %komut2%=="degistir"(
    if %komut3%=="" goto null 
    if %komut4%=="" goto null 
    if %komut5%=="" goto null 
    setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
    set str=%komut3%
    set str=%str:!komut5!=!komut4!%
    echo %str%
    pause
)
if %komut2%=="bul"(
    if %komut3%=="" goto null 
    if %komut4%=="" goto null 
    Echo.%komut3%| findstr /C:%komut4%>nul && (Echo.EVET) || (Echo.HAYIR)
    pause
)


:null
color c
echo Deger null olamaz!KOD:2
pause
```

You can say why komuts are empty beacause I want user input them like `api.bat set komut1=metin set komut2=bul ...`

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you mean by "unexpected time"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't declared `%komut1%`, and therefore the `if` command failed as well. And if the command `if` executed (right at the line #3), then it would be:

```
if =="metin" goto metinapi
   ^
   Error here, because "%komut1%" is equal to ""
```

To fix this, you may have to include double quotes `"` before and after `%komut1%`:

```
if "%komut1"=="metin" goto metinapi
```

Now not only that, but you may have to edit more commands in order to make it working, like after you fix line #3, you'll have to fix line #4 and #5, etc...